# How to see what package a function comes from?

Tags: julia

How can see from which package a function (or some other object) originates? For example the function

```
take!()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the `@which` macro:

```
@which take!

Base
```

Comment: also note `@edit`